# Determine cause of CPU Halt

Tags: linux-kernel, x86

I'm working on a research project that involves developing a new DVFS algorithm for Intel machines. To do this we're utilizing some of the code from the intel_pstates driver to actually determine the pstate for each individual CPU and using the wmsr function to set that value to registers (IA32_PERF_CTL). The problem we're encountering is when we run benchmarks, the CPU will randomly halt (not kernel panic or system hang). Is there a way we can setup a trace or another method to record the value that was trying to be written to the MSRs?

If this is the wrong group to submit this to, please let me know which would be a more appropriate group.

Thanks!

(EDIT: Corrected which register we're writing to)

Comment: While this question is technically on-topic here since debugging crashes is something system administrators also do, it's very developer-oriented, so it would be better on [so]. I voted to migrate the question there; if the question hasn't been migrated yet by the time you see this and you decide to repost on [so], please delete this copy.

Comment: To me the answer is obvious: you plug in a hardware debugger.

Comment: I agree that this question is off-topic here, not so much because it is developer-oriented as because it has no clear connection to Unix & Linux.  And, if the obvious answer is a hardware debugger, does it belong on [SO] or [SU] or Electrical Engineering.SE?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has no clear connection to Unix & Linux.

Comment: By the way, if Bryan E. and user261074 are the same person, you should use the [contact form](/contact) and select ‘‘I need to merge user profiles’’ to have your accounts merged. You’ll then be able to [edit], comment on, and accept answers to your question.